# Convert an ISO formatted date to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I am writing a SQL query using SQL Server Management Studio and there are some NVARCHAR type values in ISO date format (example: `20130302T164800`). I need to convert them to a DATETIME

I tried the `Convert()` function but it causes an exception:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your string is *not* an accepted SQL Server datetime format. SQL Server recognises the **ISO8601** format, which is:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm
```

Which would be **2013-03-02T16:48:00** for your date above.

See [Date And Time Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx) section.

So the following statement will fail:

```
declare @date nvarchar(max) = '20130302T164800'

select convertedDate = cast(@date as datetime)
```

If you convert the string to the **ISO8601** format, the statement will work:

```
declare @date nvarchar(max) = '2013-03-02T16:48:00'

select convertedDate = cast(@date as datetime)
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11757).

You can update your format to one SQL Server recognises and cast the string to a datetime in one statement:

```
declare @date nvarchar(max) = '20130302T164800'

select cast(left(@date, 4)
  + '-' + substring(@date,5,2)
  + '-' + substring(@date,7,5)
  + ':' + substring(@date,12,2)
  + ':' + substring(@date,14,2) as datetime)
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11760).

This is just an example, you could convert it to any format recognised by SQL Server, but this converts it to **ISO8601**. Basically, convert it to a different format to allow the conversion to work.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for your quick reply. That saved me from lots of trouble.