# Char to DateTime Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have one column capturedatetime(`Char(30)`):

```
2006-04-25T15:50:59.997000 PM
```

And I want to convert it and load it at other table column which have is in DateTime. either by T-sql or SSIS which ever way.

I have tried with:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2006-04-25T15:50:59.997000 PM', 126)
```

But it creates an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

**Late update:**

In this column I also have other data that is in a completely different format:

```
29-JAN-10 08.57.41.000000 PM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701421/convert-an-iso-formatted-date-to-datetime

Comment: Thanks Declan_K7 but there is no PM or AM which I have to convert too...

Comment: no..not more I have checked whole column....Sorry for that...

Comment: Since that is not a SQL date format I doubt it will be easy.  Do you have access to .NET?

Comment: no.. I am getting that data from one table and its stored in char(30) only..

Comment: Too bad you're not using SQL 2012.... `TRY_CONVERT()` + `CASE` would have you done in no time.  You can still `PATINDEX()` your way through it.

Comment: Even in .NET simple DateTime.Parse does not convert those formats.  In .NET I would use regex to select and modify and then DateTime.Parse.

Comment: @AaronBertrand `TRY_CONVERT()` makes it easier to identify all the different formats, incredibly helpful in situations like this.  `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(d,23)) IS NULL` etc.  Rather than throwing an error you can see the records causing an error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You don't see how seeing the formats that error would help you write a query to fix the formats?  If it's just 2 known formats then no big deal, but it sounded like OP didn't have a handle on what he was dealing with.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, like I said, given known formats it's not helpful.  In general, dealing with unknown/ugly data, it is useful to observe the rows that are causing problems, and that's easy to do with `TRY_CONVERT()`.  You'd combine the known formats in your where criteria to find records that still error. ie: `WHERE COALESECE(TRY_CONVERT(),TRY_CONVERT()) IS NULL`  It's hunting them down, but you get to see the problematic data rather than an unhelpful error message, ie "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  Easier to hunt what you can see.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Did not say that was the best way. Just how I would do it. OP said based on a scan those were the only 2.  If formats get really ugly I like .NET.  Your TSQL answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(datetime,left('2006-04-25T15:50:59.997000 PM',23))
```

or

```
select convert(datetime,left(capturedatetime,23))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but when I'm running the queries you have mentioned I'm getting the error

Comment: hi some of the data doesn't containts T , istead of T there is ' ' like'29-JAN-10 08.57.41.000000 PM '. I change it but gicving me the same error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I don't have to replace the 'T', thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion for 126 requires no spaces ... I've got it to work like this:

```
declare @T varchar(50)
declare @dt datetime

set @T = '2006-04-25T15:50:59.997' 
set @dt = convert(datetime,@t,126)

select @T, @dt
```

Comment: It's the `PM` on OP's data that's the problem, so of course ignoring that makes it work.

Answer (score -1):

If you use cast, you do not even need to supply a format.  Code snippet below tested on SQL 2012 Developer version.

```
declare @var_string varchar(50) = '2006-04-25T15:50:59.997';
declare @var_datetime datetime = cast(@var_string as datetime);
select @var_string as my_string, @var_datetime as my_variable;
```

[image]