# Converting Sitecore nvarchar date representation to SQL datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sitecore

Sitecore stores all field values as nvarchars. We're looking to convert its date representation to a SQL datetime but can't find a style to match on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

The date format is `yyyymmddThhmmss`, e.g.:

```
20161007T000000
00010101T000000
```

Is this possible using SQL CONVERT? - or does it require some manual parsing?

Comment: SQL solution is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701421/convert-an-iso-formatted-date-to-datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701421/convert-an-iso-formatted-date-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following SQL Script as shown below:

```
DECLARE @DateText NVARCHAR (50) = '20161007T000000'
DECLARE @ConvertText NVARCHAR (50) = SUBSTRING(@DateText, 1, 8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@DateText, 10, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@DateText, 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@DateText, 14, 2)

SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,@ConvertText)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime format in Sitecore is stored in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

You can cast to a .Net DateTime object from a `DateField`:

```
DateField dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["Date Created"];

// DateTime object
var dateTime = dateField.DateTime;
```

You can also make use of the helpers in the `Sitecore.DateUtil` class to manipulate the values to a different format. You can read more in the [Date/time best practices](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_best_practices) document.

Comment: Unfortunately this is done at the SQL level for reporting purposes - anything I can do with SQL?

Comment: @RobBell Do you care about the time part of the field?